# What is the Relevancy of Other Foundations of Mathematics Besides ZFC

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, foundations, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In mathematics, ZFC set theory has made a significant splash; it has lead the way for very important concepts such as the incompleteness theorem, the continuum hypothesis, aleph numbers, and innumerably many other things. However, other foundations of math, such as HoTT and category theory, haven't brought forth such significant results that I know of (save applications in computer science). Has HoTT, Category Theory, or any other foundation besides ZFC yeilded significant results or have the potential for significant results?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Incompleteness has little connection with ZFC.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was more referring to how set theory led to the theorem, as opposed to being used in the proof itself.

Comment: If extensions of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ count - they're used all the time in set theory to obtain interesting and significant results. Assuming large cardinals to prove (the consistency of) theorems and, on the other hand, showing the necessity of such assumptions is a key area in modern day set theory.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate with a direct example or possibly a link?

Comment: Well, category theory isn't a foundational theory in the way that ZFC or HoTT are, so expecting it to produce the same kinds of theorems misses the mark.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Category Theory can serve as a foundational theory.

Comment: @Stephen Well, there are several examples and it feels wrong to just pick one out at will - it's like asking a parent which of their siblings they like the most. But, since you asked, here is an example: If $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, we can - using Prikrý forcing - change the cofinality of $\kappa$ to $\omega$ (in the generic extension) w/o collapsing cardinals. On the other hand it was later shown that in order to change the cofinality of a given uncountable, regular cardinal $\kappa$ to $\omega$ while preserving cardinals, there has to be an inner model with a measurable cardinal.

Comment: @Stefan - Not really. There are categories whose associated theories can work as foundational theories, but "category theory" does not mean "the theory of a particular kind of category".

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Well, fair point. However, my missuse of terminology is just similar to calling set theory a foundation for mathematics instead of, say, $\operatorname{ZFC}$. So, yeah... There are theories that take categories as their base in order to formulate a foundation for mathematics.

Comment: @Stefan no, actually, it's not true that there are theories that take categories as their base to formulate a foundation for mathematics in the same way that ZFC takes sets as its base.  There are theories that use the *language* of category theory to formulate a foundation of mathematics, such as ETCS, but the basic objects in such theories are still set-like.  In principle there could be foundational theories that take categories as their base, but I'm not aware of any such theory that's been fleshed out enough to actually found mathematics on.

Comment: HoTT/UF goes one step in that direction by taking (higher) groupoids as its base objects, but the step from groupoids to categories is a big one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, to correct a common misconception: category theory is not a foundation for mathematics.  Category theory is a language that can be used to describe lots of kinds of mathematics, including some foundations of mathematics, such as Lawvere's [Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS); but those foundations are not the same as category theory.

Second, I would say that one reason ZFC gave rise to so many important consequences is that it was the *first* precise foundation for mathematics.  In some sense, this is a historical accident; in principle another foundation such as ETCS or type theory could have been developed first, and in that case it would have been *that* foundation giving rise to all those significant developments, most of which are largely insensitive to the particular foundation of mathematics in which they are formulated.

Now that we are familiar with the *notion* of "foundation of mathematics", and many of the benefits of having such a foundation have already been reaped, we shouldn't expect "new" foundations to impact mathematics in the same way that ZFC did.  Instead, their effects will be more incremental: providing better ways to formalize certain parts of mathematics, or enabling new mathematics that wasn't possible in ZFC.  But this does not mean that, taken in their own, they are any less "foundational" than ZFC.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say that $\operatorname{ZFC}$ was the first precise foundation for mathematics. Before the mathematical community mostly agreed to work within $\operatorname{ZFC}$, several variants thereof have been suggested and I imagine that they were treated more or less as equally important for at least some time.

Comment: Let me air some tangential frustration of language. I don't now of any mathematics which cannot be formalized in some extension of ZFC (I'm including things like NF which is still open as to whether or not it is consistent relative to any known theory). In other foundations this is slightly less pronounced because you sort of assume various large cardinal equivalents from the get go (read: universe like types, objects and so on). But ultimately, is there an actual example of something that we don't know how to interpret as sets in a sufficiently strong extension of ZFC?

Comment: Actually, I image that they have been treated as equally unimportant for some time. (While I can't see myself working without a precisely formulated foundational theory, many mathematicians can and do - even today. And they rarely seem to run into serious trouble.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Don't take my word for it, as I barely know the basics of it. But as far as I understood Nicola Gambino's lecture series during this year's YST workshop, the univalence axiom of homotopy type theory seems to be unlikely to be modeled within known extensions of $\operatorname{ZFC}$.

Comment: @Stefan: I was led to understand that this is perfectly doable if you have some inaccessible cardinals lying around (infinitely many? class of them?). At least when talking about objects below the first inaccessible or something like that. Which for me, as far as things go, is a perfectly valid way to formalize something.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That sounds kind of familiar to me - especially the 'smallness condition' to only consider objects below some inaccessible. In a quick discussion I had with him after one of the lectures, he outlined an argument that seemed to suggest that without such a smallness condition, it may not be possible to obtain such a model. But, as I've said previously, don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Stefan: If nothing else, whatever your set theoretic inclination, adding "there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals" is not a huge leap of faith. I agree it is tricky, but not to say it cannot be done entirely.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think the exact history of whether ZFC or other similar theories was first is relevant to the question or the answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Synthetic homotopy theory, using univalence and higher inductive types, cannot be formalized directly in ZFC.  True, one can invoke the theorem/conjecture that HoTT/UF has models in ZFC to *translate* it into statements that make sense in ZFC, but that's different from actually formalizing it as written.  I'm not claiming the dividing line is perfectly sharp, but there is at least a continuum, and synthetic homotopy theory is way off on the other end of it.  In particular, I think it's fair to say that no one equipped only with ZFC would have *invented* synthetic homotopy theory.

Comment: Mike, just for the sake of clarity (and again, my gripe with the natural language semantics of these discussions). When you say "directly in ZFC" do you mean "pure ZFC" or "ZFC+whatever reasonably sounding large cardinals you want"? And I'm not arguing that language is the basis of thought, and a different language can therefore allow you to come up with new ideas.

Comment: @AsafKaragila the latter.  In general I think these sorts of questions comparing different *approaches* to foundations should be divorced from the details of specific versions of each approach, so I tend to (abusively, I admit) use "ZFC" to refer to ZFC or some reasonable extension of it, and similarly "HoTT/UF" does not refer to any one specific formal system.

Comment: Okay, good. Because people use things like "ZFC can't prove this and that" to mean literally "ZFC cannot prove something" and at the same time "we can formulate in ZFC such and such" to mean some reasonable extension. And this abuse of language can be hard to keep track of, especially when people from different part of mathematics talk about this (I would hardly ever be confused when a set theorist says something like that, because I will usually be aware of the context, conventions and jargon; but with you, well, I can't be sure without asking).

Comment: @MikeShulman hasn't someone removed the assumption of inaccessibles for relative consistency of UF? Or is this in the works?

Comment: @DavidRoberts oh, maybe.  Colin McLarty perhaps?  I don't remember the details, so I didn't want to make any claim, and it didn't seem particularly relevant to the main point.

Comment: @MikeShulman no, I was asking for other reasons, since I saw this point referenced in a logic paper from a non-HoTT person. (I found the paper you're probably thinking of -- http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6714 -- but there were some doubts raised by Awodey, so I'll ask Colin directly)

Comment: A salient question here is exactly what we mean or want when we use the term "foundation for mathematics". This paper, though I disagree with some of what it contains, is a nice start at analysing these notions: http://philpapers.org/rec/LINOUT

Answer (score 2):

A meta comment: Zermelo set theory was initially developed over a century ago. HoTT has only been around a decade or so. Gödel's incompleteness theorems were published in 1931, over two decades after Zermelo set theory was initially developed. It seems a bit unfair to expect that HoTT should have already produced similarly groundbreaking new results.